# PHP error: Warning: ociparse() parameter 1 to be resource

Tags: php, oracle, oracle-call-interface

As there is not ready made function in oracle to validate the Query so created.
So I tried below code to check whether the QUERY is valid or not.

```
if(isset($_POST['btn_Submit_Query']))
            {
                $check_query=$_POST['txtQuery'];
                echo $check_query;
                $valid = false;
                $stmt = oci_parse($DB, $check_query);
                echo "Statement" . $stmt;
                //oci_define_by_name($stmt, 'NUMBER_OF_ROWS', $number_of_rows);
                oci_execute($stmt, OCI_DEFAULT);
                echo oci_num_rows($stmt);
            }
```

I got following Warnings in the Execution:

```
Warning: oci_parse() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in D:\xampp\htdocs\app\DashBoardSite\Admin\querybuilder.php on line 899
Statement
Warning: oci_execute() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in D:\xampp\htdocs\app\DashBoardSite\Admin\querybuilder.php on line 902

Warning: oci_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in D:\xampp\htdocs\app\DashBoardSite\Admin\querybuilder.php on line 903
```

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

You must first connect to the database. This connection must a "resource" to variable $DB.